# Same header, different lib in different namespaces

Tags: c++

I have two different C headers (contains `extern "C"`), that overlap from 80%. Each header has different *.lib with its functions. In my code, I need to use both headers in different namespaces. I can compile and link my program, but the behaviour seems to "join" both libs into one and use only one set of functions and other one is replaced.

**EDIT:**

Could it be done, if I use dyamic linkage ? Each lib has its own dll and resolve which dll to use according to created object (unlink old and link new dll and vice versa) ?

Comment: C doesn't do namespaces.

Comment: @PeteBecker In my C++ code are namespaces, headers are C

Comment: Understood. C code can't go in namespaces, because namespaces don't exist in C.

Answer (score 3):

When you make a function `extern "C"`, your forego the name-mangling that avoids problems with name space collisions.  You are, by definition, saying that there will be a single function with the given name, undecorated by class or namespace information.

So, you can't do what you're trying to do.  A C program can only use one or the other copy of each of the `extern "C"` functions..  A C++ program can only use one or the other of each of the `extern "C"` programs.

You will have to rename the functions in one (or both) of the libraries to be able to use both in a single program (probably by adding different systematic prefixes to the names exposed by the libraries).  Or, if the libraries are written in C++, lose the `extern "C"` attribute.  You will have to change something to break the naming collisions.

Comment: I took "C headers" to mean headers for code in a C library. If that's the case, removing `extern "C"` will just break things; one or the other library will have to have its functions renamed.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That's another way of looking at it.  If there are two C libraries with an 80% overlap in the names of the functions, you can't use the '80% overlap' code reliably in a single program, whether the remainder of the program is in C or C++ or both. I agree with your "C doesn't do namespaces" comment.  And I'm explaining (trying to explain) one way of looking at the question.

Comment: In other words, headers use does not matter, the name resolution on linking stage is the problem.

Comment: @Basilevs: the headers matter because they define the names by which the functions will be called.  And all the `extern "C"` function names used by a single program must be unique across the program. You're right, though, that link-time is where the problems show themselves most clearly (usually).  In theory, it might be possible that all of one library is linked OK, and the 20% of the other library is linked, but it is seldom that a library is so compartmentalized that that will actually work.  There'll usually be something that causes a linkage conflict (which is a good thing in this case!).